# Перестал работать tomcat8.

Tags: tomcat

Вчера уходил домой все работало хорошо. Сегодня же, придя на работу, не смог получить доступ к GeoServerу, размещенного на tomcatе. Попробывал зайти на tomcat manager, а страница не прогружается. Проверил в командной строке, tomcat запущен, открываю лог, ошибок не нашел, но сервер не работает. Что делать не знаю. Вот лог [catalina.2016-02-09.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0RQeUHpAFUkTzhmbl81UG9VOGc/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1):

Проблема оказалось в том, что после перезагрузки виртуальной машины, заработали две версии tomcata.